# How to fire an event using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in wpf

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, begininvoke

I am get confused with the following code.

```
someObject
.Dispatcher
.BeginInvoke(new SomeDelegate(SomeEvent), SomeParamater);
```

here SomeDelegate is a delegate, 
SomeEvent is an event of class.

When I am running the code, SomeEvent is fired and the event handler gets the control.

Can some one explain how it is running?

Comment: Did you read the MSDN documentation of [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)?

Comment: @Clemens I have gone through it, but the signature says we can pass the delegate type not the event.

Comment: How is your `SomeDelegate` defined?

Comment: @Clemens The `SomeDelegate` is like the following               `public delegate void ViewItemsUnloaded(object obj);`

Comment: Then your event is certainly defined like this: `public event ViewItemsUnloaded SomeEvent;`. The [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) defines the event method signature, BeginInvoke calls the event method, similar to a direct call like `SomeEvent(SomeParameter);`.

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.80).aspx): `A delegate is a type that references a method. Once a delegate is assigned a method, it behaves exactly like that method. The delegate method can be used like any other method`. The delegate passed to BeginInvoke holds a reference to the method to ba called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was: how to invoke an event defined as

```
public event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> SomeEvent;
```

via `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`?

It is done like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SomeEventArgs>(SomeEvent), this, new SomeEventArgs());
```

or any other value instead of `this` as second argument, wich gets passed to the event handler as the `sender` argument.